# NoReverseMatch error in Django Tutorial

Tags: python, html, django

I'm following the Django tutorial and have got half way through this page:[Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/)

I get the error 'NoReverseMatch' with the exception value being "Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '(None,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P[0-9]+)/vote/$']".  I have gone through and tried to check for types as best as possible but any help in resolving this issue will be great. I'll put the relevant code down below but let me know if you need any other code. Thanks

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404,render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import choice, question
from django.template import loader

##def index(request):
##    return HttpResponse("Hello World. You're at the polls index.")

##def detail(request, question_id):
##    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)
##    try:
##        Question = question.objects.get(pk=question_id)
##    except question.DoesNotExist:
##        raise Http404("Question does not exist")
##    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html',{'Question':Question})

def detail(request, question_id):
   Question = get_object_or_404(question, pk=question_id)
   return render(request, 'polls/detail.html',{'question': question})

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)

def index(request):
    latestQuestionList = question.objects.order_by('-pubDate')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    contect = {
        'latestQuestionList': latestQuestionList,
    }
    #output = ', '.join([q.questionText for q in latestQuestionList])
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def vote(request, question_id):
    Question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selectedChoice = question.choiceSet.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, choice.DoesNotExist):
            return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
                'question': question,
                'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
            })
    else:
            selectedChoice.votes += 1
            selectedChoice.save()
            return
    HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))

def results(request, question_id):
    Question = get_object_or_404(question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html',{'Question': Question})
```

settings.py
 """
    Django settings for mysite project.

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'i$8b5*0iugjm2i$&0x2_&e@dpm_chv_c@82-9rkbr1$e7tw_%r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

models.py
    from django.utils import timezone
    import datetime
    from django.db import models
    from django.utils.encoding import *

```
# Create your models here.

class question(models.Model):
    questionText = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pubDate = models.DateTimeField('Date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questionText
    def wasPublishedRecently(self):
        return self.pubDate >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choiceText = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choiceText
#ADMIN PASSWORD IS Timberland
```

admin.py
    from django.contrib import admin
    from .models import question
    # Register your models here.
    admin.site.register(question)
urls.py
    from django.conf.urls import url, include

```
from . import views
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
    ]
```

Comment: The only `reverse()` call that I see in your code is this one: `HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))` I don't see one for "vote".

Comment: Compare your form in `polls/templates/polls/detail.html` to this one in the tutorial and make sure you have `question.id` in your `action` attribute: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form

Comment: Also your `results` view should be using lowercase `question` to avoid a conflict with the model name, check the example about halfway down this page: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/